# Probabilty Density as a Quadratic?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

I'm trying to express the natural log of a probability density function.

$$\displaystyle p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
$$h(x) = ln(p(x))$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right)$$

attempting h(x) as a quadratic in the the form $ax^2+bx+c$

I think I may be a bit lost.

$$\displaystyle h(x)=ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)+ln\left(exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)+\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=exp\left(ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)\right)+\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}+\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)^2+\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
$$\displaystyle h(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}+\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

Comment: What’s the issue? Just expand the second term in last line and collect like powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right up until the fifth line, I'm not sure how you added an $\exp(\cdot)$ around your $\ln(\cdot)$. But starting from your fifth line, we have the following:

$$ h(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) + \left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) $$

$$ = \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) - \left(\frac{x^2-2\mu x + \mu^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) $$

$$ = - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}x^2 + \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}x - \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} + \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) .$$

So, you have

$$ a = - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} , $$

$$ b = \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} , $$

$$ c = - \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} + \ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) . $$

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense I see where I went off. Very clear answer!

Comment: You're very welcome!